# How to install iOS5 simulator in xcode7.3.1?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode7.3

I want to develop an iOS application also support in iOS5.I am going to develop in Xcode7.3.1.But I can’t find iOS5 simulator in Xcode7.3.1.Is it possible run iOS app with iOS5 simulator in Xcode7.3.1?.Here i attached one image showing all available simulators.Here i cant find old simulators.How to solve this issue?Please help me.

[image]

Comment: No you can only add simulator upto iOS 8.

Comment: yes that thing i know.anyway to install iOS5 to xcode7.3.1?